# Как правильно называть счетчик в цикле for для массива?

Tags: c++, стандарт

Есть какой-то вектор. Допустим `vector<int> layersArr;`

Как будет правильно назвать счетчик в цикле for, для лучшей читаемости кода?

```
for(int i = 0; i < layersArr.size(); i++);
```

Или же

```
for(int layer = 0; layer < layersArr.size(); layer++);
```

Comment: тут нет никакого итератора....  Для индексации  лучше  тип   size_t   чем  int, а называть  в цикле можете по любому, но  эти имена фигурируют только в цикле, поэтому достаточно назвать одним символом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i`, `j` и `k` - общепринятые переменные для цикла. Это тянется уже лет 50 с фортрана. Там они были по умолчанию целочисленные и математикам так было понятно и очевидно - вспомните математические обозначения для суммы-произведения с их индексами.

Поэтому, в большинстве случаев, если цикл небольшой (строк 20, влазит на экран), а переменные `i`, `j` и `k` используются как индексы массива, то всем все очевидно. Но если вдруг окажется, что `j` используется в качестве первой размерности, а `i` второй - вот это вызовет подозрения.

Если же индекс не просто индекс (у него есть какая то дополнительная сущность), то лучше дать смысловое название.

Вернемся к Вашему примеру.

Если размер цикла одна-две строки, то `i` - это нормальное имя, всем будет очевидно.
Если тело цикла 5-10 и внутри ещё есть цикл или сложное условие - лучше сделать имя смысловое.
Если тело стало ещё больше - это повод задуматься о том, что бы сделать небольшой рефакторинг. И проблема сводится к предыдущим.

В многих случаях можно сделать красивее, если использовать стандартную библиотеку алгоритмов. те же [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), [`find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_if), [`count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) уберут много циклов.

Answer (score 3):

**Итератор** (не **индекс**!) будет правильно использовать так:

```
for(vector<int>::iterator it = layersArr.begin(); it != layersArr.end(); ++it)
```

или так:

```
for(auto it = layersArr.begin(); it != layersArr.end(); ++it)
```

или даже так:

```
for(auto elem: layersArr)
```

Что же касается названия переменной - то если программируете в команде - пользуйтесь уставом монастыря, так сказать, стилем именования, принятым в команде.

Если программируете сами - поступайте так, как вам удобнее, а главное, понятнее - чтоб потом не начинать мучительно соображать, что это за переменная - `i5q8_3s`...

Если бы существовало правило - именовать итераторы только так, и никак иначе - оно было бы реализовано в стандарте языка :)

Comment: Ну да, вопрос был именно про индекс, но за итератор тоже спасибо. Я программирую сам, но мне хочется, чтобы код был читаем для других. Поэтому и не знаю, что будет более правильным.

Comment: Тогда спрашивайте у того, для кого конкретно вы программируете, кто будет читать вашу программу - к чему он привык :) Лично мне в *вашем конкретном примере* больше нравится `i`, потому что `layer` - это слой, а не индекс стоя в векторе. `layerNo` было бы понятнее, но многословнее; читать было бы просто, но исправлять код - долго, так что (опять же, *лично* я) предпочитаю для индексов `i`, `j`, `k` - это традиция еще со времен фортрана...

Answer (score 0):

Всё от ситуации зависит. Если у вас два вложенных цикла на разные массивы, то нужно чтобы индексы не перепутались у Вас в голове называть с именем массива.

Так **не**правильно  :

```
vector<int> Arr;
vector<double> Money;
int i,j;
for( i = 0;j<Arr.size();++i)
   for ( j=0;j<Money.size();++i)
       Money[i] += Arr[j];
```

Здесь ошибки с циклах, **не то** сравниваете, **не то** прибавляете, индекс **не из того** массива.

Можно написать так:

```
vector<int> Arr;
vector<double> Money;
int ArrInd,MoneyInd;
for( ArrInd = 0;ArrInd<Arr.size();++ArrInd)
   for ( MoneyInd=0;MoneyInd<Money.size();++MoneyInd)
       Money[MoneyInd] += Arr[ArrInd];
```

Comment: если ArrInd не нужны за пределами цикла, то лучше оъявлять их прямо там, ну и имеет смысл использовать auto, т.к. контейнеры отдают размер в size_t, а не int

Comment: Циклы бывают длинными, на два экрана. И память кто куда указывает исчезает. Массивы размера в два гига бывают очень редко, инта хватает. @goldstar_labs

Comment: есть такое понятие, как ограничение области видимости. Чем лучше ее ограничить, тем меньше шансов в будущем на ошибку. А вот то, что "инта хватает" - я бы не спешил так говорить. Уже всем 640 кб хватало.

Comment: **int** был у спрашивающего. Может ему обязательно он нужен.  @KoVadim

Comment: может. это очень сложная и больная тема для сообщества - использовать ли int для итерации по циклу.